# Is it really necessary to have a generic tag for e-commerce, and specific tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

We actually have [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce), which is described as a generic tag for e-commerce modules, and that could be used for modules such as Drupal Commerce, and Ubercart; we have also [drupal-commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal-commerce), and [ubercart](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubercart), which are very specific for some modules.

Do we really need to have [commerce](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commerce)? In few cases, the tag was the only one used for questions about modules included in the Drupal Commerce project; this lets me think users use that because "commerce" is the short name for the Drupal Commerce project.

Should the tag be used to mean any questions about e-commerce done in Drupal, or to mean any questions about e-commerce, excluding questions about Drupal Commerce, and Ubercart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way Drupal modules are named, I think this is highly confusing to new users.  I don't think `commerce` is necessary because at this point nearly all Drupal sites doing e-commerce are using either Ubercart or Drupal Commerce.  Most general questions regarding e-commerce would likely regard comparing Ubercart and Drupal Commerce or integrating third-party solutions, which could have their own separate tag(s) if it became necessary.